# What does %H:%i.pid do in a .service file?

Tags: linux, systemd

Ok I have been looking all over the place and cannot find what this is doing. Below is a line from a .service file to start tightvnc on boot.

```
PIDFile=/home/username/.vnc/%H:%i.pid
```

I am assuming it is grabbing username:1.pid from the folder but I do not understand what the individual parts %H and %i are actually doing? I do know the rest of the script uses the %i in a couple other lines. specifically:

```
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i > /dev/null 2>&1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver -depth 24 -geometry 1280x800 :%i
ExecStop=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i
```

I am also unsure what the %H and %i operators are called making it hard to find them searching online. What I have been able to deduce is %H must be grabbing the username but I am unsure what number or numbers %i is grabbing.

the files in /usr/bin/vncserver are as follows with date strings:

```
May 26 16:04 username:1.log
May 26 15:56 username:1.pid
May 26 15:21 username:2.log
May 26 15:21 username:2.pid
May 26 15:21 username:3.log
May 26 15:21 username:3.pid
May 25 17:31 passwd
May 25 17:35 xstartup
May 25 17:32 xstartup.bak
```

The only reason I am adding the dates in there is because I know %H can stand for hours but I highly doubt that is what it represents here.

Comment: `.service` files aren't bash scripts, they're configuration files used by `systemd`. The `%` stuff is replaced by `systemd`.

Comment: @Barmar what tag should it be changed to instead of bash?

Comment: I just changed it to `systemd`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.service` files aren't `bash` scripts, they're unit files used by `systemd`. The structure of these files are described [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html). `%` followed by a letter are specifiers that get replaced by various system parameters:

- `%H` =    Host name
- `%i` = Instance name

Comment: No wonder I couldn't find it. I will check your answer once it lets me! Thank you :)